# Render multpile ReactJS components in Laravel without using ReactJS Router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

I want to render multiple ReactJS components in new window tab. I want to use PHP Laravel Router to render multiple components.

**I tried:**

**1.** In view file I have `<div id="root"></div>` in index.js file I have

```
ReactDOM.render(<App ></App>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I use two ReactDOM.render with different div ID and components, it gives me following error:

> Target Container is not a DOM element

I searched for this error but couldn't find the solution.

**2.** I tried below code without any router:
   I write below code in reducer(Redux) JS file on onclick event action dispatch.

```
import secondComponent from '../PathToFile';
.
.
var newWindow= window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');
var element =  document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = <secondComponent/>;
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);
```

but it results:

> [object  object]

in new window tab. Am I missing something?

Please guide me. Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I do not understand your question very well but I think you should add more root element and it is possible, I mean:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="that-component-root"></div>
```

And on your codes based on your PHP routing import each bundled files. each bundled files should inject into their own root element:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And

```
ReactDOM.render(<ThatComponentRoot />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

etc.

But I think if I understand your problem truly, It is possible your project maybe will be very complex.

Comment: Thanks for reply! In your answer, the components <App /> & <ThatComponentRoot /> are rendered at same div element 'root'? Is it correct or they are renders on two different divs. I also try with two different div ids, then they are display one upon another. If I also set the CSS display(none or block) property for them then it is fine. But for more than two components I think it is not useful way to do it and it becomes bit complex. Can you suggest the work-around for this! I am stuck on this problem badly!

Comment: @Developer, Each of them is injecting into their own div.